# Can expdp be piped directly into impdp, without intermediate files?

Tags: oracle, impdp, expdp

We often need to copy fairly large databases from one server to another. The current method uses `expdp` on the source, and *then* `impdp` on the destination. This gets pretty horrible because:

1. It takes up a lot of space to store the intermediary files.
2. It takes a lot more time than necessary because the writing and the reading happen in sequence rather than in parallel.

Is there a way to arrange things so that the `stdout` of `expdp` are piped directly into `stdin` of `impdp`? For example:

```
expdp / parfile=export.par | ssh remote impdp parfile=import.par
```

What should I put into these hypothetical `export.par` and `import.par` respectively?

If not straight `stdout` into `stdin`, can `expdp` write to and `impdp` -- read from -- TCP-socket(s)? I could have those plumbed with `netcat`...

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-0871E56B-07EB-43B3-91DA-D1F457CF6182.htm#SUTIL919

You could try import over network link maybe.

Answer (score 1):

As @mutap stated in the comments, you can expdp/impdp over the network.

Technically, you will be doing the DataPump export and import over a database link without the need for an intermediate file.

Bash PIPE is not needed.

Example:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g#NetworkExportsImports